# Variation of umbrella logo for "children's" department

Tags: logo, icon, branding, trademark

I'm a graphic designer and my company is usually very protective of our system mark. All of our centers use the same logo with simple text below to designate the location. We don't allow any alterations to the logo (font, color, layout) for any reason.

However, we are now opening a children's center and now upper management wants to alter the logo just for that department (i.e. add a flower or sun or child-friendly fonts & colors). I'm concerned because I want to preserve the integrity of our logo to keep recognition as high as possible.

What is the right thing to do? Should I allow the alteration, or fight to keep our logo unchanged? And if I should fight, does anyone have convincing arguments to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of your current logo and perhaps some sketches of what an addition would look like? To me it doesn't seem like it'd hurt the integrity of the logo if it's a small addition

Comment: It's impossible to say generically. It all depends on the particulars of your company, strategy, audience, and, of course, the logo itself. Plenty of companies stick with one logo across all products. Other companies create all sorts of variations for each individual audience.

Comment: Christine, corporate-identity programs change all the time as the business changes.  If you're in charge of CI, then determine what can be changed (e.g. color, which is not essential, or shouldn't be) while still maintaining the link to the corporation.  BUT, if the kids center (do you mean day-care?) is to be spun off, then you needn't do more than echo some element.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would only alter the logo if this Children's division will have separate functions inside of it—If it's a new 'bucket'. OR if this logo will have more of a presence than typical business units for PR or signage etc.

Additionally you may want to alter the  logo if it ever will appear next to the parent/main logo or as a collection of services.

Also maybe there is a way to just effect the type treatment area so the mark isn't touched.

Good luck with this!